# Python: do dlls loaded by ctypes share the same memory space

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes, shared-memory

I am trying to do something with dlls in Python which I know I can do in C++, but I am getting a memory exception.

If you load two dlls in C++ and provide them with the same pointer, they can both operate on the object to which the pointer points without problem.

When doing the same using Python and cytypes, the dll that creates the object is absolutely fine dereferencing that pointer  on subsequent calls, *so the passing of that pointer between Python and the C++ dll is working fine*.  However, when this pointer is provided to the second dll in the same manner, I get a very uninformative exception: *"WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0101CC84"*.

[image: ctypes dlls viewed in the debugger]

Before I start trying to debug into these dlls (which will be painful), does anyone know if Python loads these C++ dlls into the same memory space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, python.exe is the process and all DLLs are loaded into its memory space.

You may have your `.argtypes` and `restype` declared incorrectly (or not at all).  Here's an example that works:

**x.c**

```
__declspec(dllexport) const char* func1()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

**y.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void func2(const char* s)
{
    printf("%s\n",s);
}
```

**Python**

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> x = CDLL('x')
>>> x.func1.argtypes = None
>>> x.func1.restype = c_void_p
>>> y = CDLL('y')
>>> y.func2.argtypes = [c_void_p]
>>> y.func2.restype = None
>>> s = x.func1()
>>> hex(s)
'0x7ff8b4ca8000'
>>> y.func2(s)
hello
```

Note I explicitly declared the parameter `c_void_p` because `ctypes` will convert a `c_char_p` to a Python string on output and from a Python string to `char*` on input so it wouldn't prove that the same pointer can be passed from one DLL to another.

A tool like [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can be used for seeing the DLLs in the process space:

[image: Process Explorer showing Python.exe and DLLs]

Note that the address returned by `x.func1()` falls within the mapped range of `x.dll` and `y.func2(s)` displays it correctly.

Comment: Could I ask how you found this out, @Mark Tolonen?

Comment: @MikeSadler Read Windows Internals, or use a tool like SysInternals Process Explorer to see for yourself.

Comment: @MikeSadler what is likely the issue is you haven't declared the argtypes and restype correctly for the functions you are calling.  This is especially important with pointers and 64-bit OS, because parameters are default passed as int, which are 32-bit.  I'll update with a working example...